# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'json_minify'

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to implement a project following an online article, I am done with everything, installed OpenCV 4.1.2, OpenVINO 4.2.0, Python 3.7 and all other packages and libraries on my raspberry pi, including json_minify package using the command "pip install JSON-minify", but when I try to run the project, it still gives me the following error.

> from json_minify import json_minify

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'json_minify'

This is how the file looks like (conf.py) in the directory (utils) where all packages for json resides.

```
# import the necessary packages
from json_minify import json_minify
import json

class Conf:
    def __init__(self, confPath):
        # load and store the configuration and update the object's dictionary
        conf = json.loads(json_minify(open(confPath).read()))
        self.__dict__.update(conf)

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        # return the value associated with the supplied key
        return self.__dict__.get(k, None)
```

Comment: Please make sure that you use the same python version to run your script as for pip. `python -m pip install xyz` and `python main.py` is the recommended way.

Comment: I have made Python 3.7.3 as my default version, so I presume whenever I try to run anything related to Python the version is 3.7.3 by default for each command and script.  And my pip version is pip 21.1.2